# How to parse string to struct?

Tags: c, string, parsing, struct

I want to know if there is any way to convert a string like `"5ABBF13A000A01"` to the next struct using struct and union method:

```
struct xSensorData2{
    unsigned char flags;           
    unsigned int refresh_rate;
    unsigned int timestamp;
};
```

Data should be:

```
flags = 0x01 (last byte);
refresh_rate = 0x000A (two bytes);
timestamp = 5ABBF13A (four bytes);
```

I'm thinking in next struct of data:

```
struct xData{
    union{
        struct{
            unsigned char flags:8;
            unsigned int refresh_rate:16;
            unsigned int timestamp:32;
        };
        char pcBytes[8];
    };
}__attribute__ ((packed));
```

But I got a struct of 12 bytes, I think it's because bit fields don't work for different types of data. I should just convert string to array of hex, copy to `pcBytes` and have access to each field.

Update:
In stm32 platform i used this code:

```
bool bDecode_HexString(char *p)
{
uint64_t data = 0;                  /* exact width type for conversion 
*/
char *endptr = p;                   /* endptr for strtoul validation */
errno = 0;                                          /* reset errno */

data = strtoull (p, &endptr, 16);    /* convert input to uint64_t */

if (p == endptr && data == 0) {     /* validate digits converted */
    fprintf (stderr, "error: no digits converted.\n");
    return false;
}
if (errno) {    /* validate no error occurred during conversion */
    fprintf (stderr, "error: conversion failure.\n");
    return false;
}
//printf ("data: 0x%" PRIx64 "\n\n", data); /* output conerted string */

sensor.flags = data & 0xFF;                             /* set flags */
sensor.rate = (data >> CHAR_BIT) & 0xFFFF;              /* set rate */
sensor.tstamp = (data >> (3 * CHAR_BIT)) & 0xFFFFFFFF;  /* set timestamp */

    return true;

/* output sensor struct */
//    printf ("sensor.flags : 0x%02" PRIx8 "\nsensor.rate  : 0x%04" PRIx16
//            "\nsensor.tstamp: 0x%08" PRIx32 "\n", sensor.flags, sensor.rate,
//            sensor.tstamp);
}
```

and call the function:

```
char teste[50] = "5ABBF13A000A01";
bDecode_HexString(teste);
```

I get `data = 0x3a000a01005abbf1`

Comment: First, you want to convert the string to a 64 bit integer. Then I would not use `union` for reasons you are experiencing (`struct` padding, in particular). Why not just directly assign each member? I know it's not clever, but it's clear, reliable, and, in this case, concise since you only have 3 structure members. For example, something like, `s.flags = (value & 0xff);`, and `s.refresh_rate = (value >> 8) & 0xffff;` and `s.timestamp = (value >> 24) & 0xffffffff;`. Of course, this assumes you're using a 64 bit integer for `value`.

Comment: I would use `strtoull` to convert the string into a 64-bit value. And then use shifting and masking to extract the fields. Or you can break the string into three pieces, and convert each piece with `strtoul`.

Comment: Your structure would likely be 12 bytes on a 32-bit machine because of structure alignment to word boundaries.  You have 8 bytes for the pcBytes field, and up to 32 bits = 4 bytes for the anonymous field.

Comment: Thanks @lurker. I will test this way..

Comment: Yes @Mulliganaceous

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are still struggling with the separation of your input into `flags, rate & timestamp`, then the suggestions in the comments regarding using an unsigned type to hold your input string converted to a value, and using the exact width types provided in `<stdint.h>`, will avoid potential problems inherent in manipulating signed types (e.g. potential *sign-extension*, etc.)

If you want to separate the values and coordinate those in struct, that is 100% fine. The work come in separating the individual `flags, rate & timestamp`. How you choose to store them so they are convenient within your code is up to you. A simple struct utilizing exact-width type could be:

```
typedef struct {    /* struct holding sensor data */
    uint8_t  flags;
    uint16_t rate;
    uint32_t tstamp;   
} sensor_t;
```

In a conversion from `char *` to `uint64_t` with `strtoull`, you have two primary validation checks:

1. utilize both the pointer to the string to convert and the `endptr` parameter to validate that digits were in fact converted (`strtoull` sets `endptr` to point 1-character after the last digit converted). You use this to compare `endptr` with the original pointer for the data converted to confirm that a conversion took place (if no digits were converted the original pointer and `endptr` will be the same and the value returned will be zero); and
2. you set `errno = 0;` before the conversion and then check again after the conversion to insure no error occurred during the conversion itself. If `strtoull` encounters an error, value exceeds range, etc.., `errno` is set to a positive value.
3. (and if you have specific range validations, e.g. you want to store the result in a size less than that of the conversion, like `uint32_t` instead of `uint64_t`, you need to validate the final value can be stored in the smaller type)

A simple approach would be:

```
    uint64_t data = 0;                  /* exact width type for conversion */
    ...
    char *p = argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "0x5ABBF13A000A01",  /* input */
        *endptr = p;                    /* endptr for strtoul validation */
    errno = 0;          /* reset errno */
    ...
    data = strtoull (p, &endptr, 0);    /* convert input to uint64_t */

    if (p == endptr && data == 0) {     /* validate digits converted */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: no digits converted.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    if (errno) {    /* validate no error occurred during conversion */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: conversion failure.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    printf ("data: 0x%" PRIx64 "\n\n", data); /* output conerted string */
```

Finally, separating the value in `data` into the individual values of `flags, rate & timestamp`, can be done with simple shifts & ANDS, e.g.

```
    sensor_t sensor = { .flags = 0 };   /* declare instance of sensor */
    ...
    sensor.flags = data & 0xFF;                             /* set flags */
    sensor.rate = (data >> CHAR_BIT) & 0xFFFF;              /* set rate */
    sensor.tstamp = (data >> (3 * CHAR_BIT)) & 0xFFFFFFFF;  /* set timestamp */

    /* output sensor struct */
    printf ("sensor.flags : 0x%02" PRIx8 "\nsensor.rate  : 0x%04" PRIx16
            "\nsensor.tstamp: 0x%08" PRIx32 "\n", sensor.flags, sensor.rate,
            sensor.tstamp);
```

Putting it altogether, you could do something similar to:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <limits.h>

typedef struct {    /* struct holding sensor data */
    uint8_t  flags;
    uint16_t rate;
    uint32_t tstamp;   
} sensor_t;

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    uint64_t data = 0;                  /* exact width type for conversion */
    sensor_t sensor = { .flags = 0 };   /* declare instace of sensor */
    char *p = argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "0x5ABBF13A000A01",  /* input */
        *endptr = p;                    /* endptr for strtoul validation */
    errno = 0;          /* reset errno */

    data = strtoull (p, &endptr, 0);    /* convert input to uint64_t */

    if (p == endptr && data == 0) {     /* validate digits converted */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: no digits converted.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    if (errno) {    /* validate no error occurred during conversion */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: conversion failure.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    printf ("data: 0x%" PRIx64 "\n\n", data); /* output conerted string */

    sensor.flags = data & 0xFF;                             /* set flags */
    sensor.rate = (data >> CHAR_BIT) & 0xFFFF;              /* set rate */
    sensor.tstamp = (data >> (3 * CHAR_BIT)) & 0xFFFFFFFF;  /* set timestamp */

    /* output sensor struct */
    printf ("sensor.flags : 0x%02" PRIx8 "\nsensor.rate  : 0x%04" PRIx16
            "\nsensor.tstamp: 0x%08" PRIx32 "\n", sensor.flags, sensor.rate,
            sensor.tstamp);

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/struct_sensor_bitwise
data: 0x5abbf13a000a01

sensor.flags : 0x01
sensor.rate  : 0x000a
sensor.tstamp: 0x5abbf13a
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Good comment, will do. And good catch, I'm so used to 64-bit boxes today, those 4-bit longs sneak by every now and then.

Comment: Thanks @david-c-rankin. I will use your method.

Comment: Just one question. How errno  will validate if one error occur?

Comment: `man strtoll` "*If an underflow occurs, strtoll()returns LLONG_MIN. If an overflow occurs, strtol() returns LLONG_MAX.  In both cases, errno is set to ERANGE.*" (LL in context for L)

Comment: i'm using this in STM32 microcontroller, so i don't know if all things in manual applies to this. I'm testing this code microcontroller and some strange happens. My string is `5ABBF13A001E01` and strtoll returns `0x3a001e01005abbf1`.Do you know why?

Comment: @R.Rodrigues post the exact conversion and I'll look at it. It would help to edit your question and **add** the code to the end of your question (don't erase any parts of the original -- or comments and answers won't make sense any more) I'll try and look up what a STM32 microcontroller is in the mean time.

Comment: @R.Rodrigues according to [Basic data types in ARM C and C++](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armcc/armcc_chr1359125009502.htm) arm has a full 8-byte `long long`, so you are not exceeding the type-size. The problem must be in your code prior to the conversion.

Comment: Could be because arm is 32-bit and pc 64-bit? I will post the code anyway..

Comment: I don't think so, if you look at the link in my comment, the stm32 has a full-size 8-byte `long long` which is the same as an x86-64 pc. (that means they just use 2-registers for the 8-byte number -- much like an x86 pc does)

Comment: Ok, let me look into what `bDecode_HexString(teste);` is -- that's not a standard C-library function. You should be using `long long val = strtoull (teste, NULL, 16);` (or you can use an actual `endptr` parameter instead of `NULL` so you can validate a conversion occurred). I have a bit of work to do, but I should be back with you in an hour or so.

Comment: You can NOT declare `uint64_t data = 0;` **inside** `bDecode_HexString()` and expect to use it **outside** the function!!! When you declare any variable inside a function, it is declared local to that function within the *function stack memory*. When the function returns, that memory is destroyed (released for reuse). You invoke *Undefined Behavior* when you attempt to access a variable that has gone out of scope. (the only caveat, is a function can always return its own `type`, but `data` ain't `bool`) Change `bool bDecode_HexString(char *p, uint64_t *data)` and pass a pointer to `data`.

Comment: i changed the optimization level of compiler to level 0 and strtoull returns the expected value

Comment: i don't want to return the data, just process data and put the values in sensor_t struct. So, i think that this isn't the problem

Comment: Ok then it was an optimization issue -- you will need to chase down why. Something along the way was optimized out or wrong. That I have no clue about the inter-workings of the STM32 compiler optimizations.

Comment: I don't know why optimization don't works right... But thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 1):

Here, you have a string of length 14, representing a 7-byte value, consisting of 14 hexadecimal values. Consider this code using `strtol`, which hexadecimally converts your string into a long int, and then decodes it digit-wise.

```
uint64_t n = strtoul(str, NULL, 16); // Convert to hexadecimal
int flags = n % 0x10;
int refresh_rate = (n / 0x100) % 0x100000;
int timestamp = n / 0x1000000;
```

Here is a test case (#import `<stdlib.h>`):

```
char str[16] = "5ABBF13EE00AFF";
uint64_t n = strtoul(str, NULL, 16); // Convert to hexadecimal

// Use divide and mod to extract digit segment
int flags = n % 0x100;
int refresh_rate = (n / 0x100) % 0x10000;
int timestamp = n / 0x1000000;
// Print timestamp, refresh rate, and flags
printf("%p %p %p", timestamp, refresh_rate, flags);
```

The expected result is `0x5abbf13e 0xe00a 0xff` as expected.

Comment: Recommend `strtoul` and `long long unsigned`, or better include `stdint.h` and use `uint64_t` exact width type to avoid potential problems with signed values.